# Adding hAxis.gridlines to EmbeddedChart

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization, google-sheets

I am trying to make a time series plot in Google Sheets using Apps Script. It seems that the object I need is the class `EmbeddedChartBuilder`. After looking at the examples in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart), here is what I wrote:

```js
function getChart(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
  .addRange(sheet.getRange("D2:D65"))
  .addRange(sheet.getRange("A2:A65"))
  .addRange(sheet.getRange("B2:B65"))
  .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```

By default the plot shows up with **only horizontal gridlines** (i.e. vertical axis gridline):

[image]

but I would like to also have vertical gridlines. It turns out that `EmbeddedChartBuilder` has a `setOptions` method, which is documented [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/embedded-chart-builder#setOption%28String,Object%29). This is the point where I get confused: looking at the [Google Visualization API Reference documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference), it seems that the [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#Configuration_Options) for a LineChart include `hAxis.gridlines`. So I changed my code accordingly:

```js
function getChart(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var chart = sheet.newChart()
  .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
  .addRange(sheet.getRange("D2:D65"))
  .addRange(sheet.getRange("A2:A65"))
  .addRange(sheet.getRange("B2:B65"))
  .setPosition(5, 5, 0, 0)
  .setOption('hAxis.gridlines.count', -1)
  .setOption('hAxis.gridlines.color','#000000')
  .build();
  sheet.insertChart(chart);
}
```

but the chart didn't change at all, still no sign of vertical gridlines. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: Vertical gridlines are supported only on charts with continuous x-axes (type "number", "date", "datetime", "timeofday").  I suspect that while your axis is showing dates, it is actually a "string" type axis.  You need to either adjust the spreadsheet so that it knows that column is a date column, or you need to create a DataView to translate the strings into Dates.  I'm not very familiar with the Apps Script environment, but from what I can see in the documentation, I don't believe you can go the DataView route (but I could be wrong).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @asgallant, you were right there was data type problem. I thought I already changed manually the time column to date, but it didn't work out, probably because that column is the output of a script that converts Unix time in formatted string. When I changed the output of the script to date everything worked out well. Perhaps you want to change your comment in an answer?